# Switching compiler in QMake file

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I am running CentOS 6 and would like to switch c++ compilers to ver 4.7 using a conditional (contains) in the qmake file.

This [superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos) shows how to set some environment variables to use a later compiler - but I don't think this will work in qmake.  How would I integrate this into a qmake file?

Comment: Obviously, you need to redefine `QMAKE_CC`, `QMAKE_CXX` and `QMAKE_LINK.` But I just don't understand why do you want it. It's highly likely that it will only break everything.

Comment: I need to compile some code written with C++14 features on CentOS 6.  So I need a gcc 4.7 compiler to run on CentOS 6.